# NservicebusPubSub

Tags: nservicebus

I am using the pub sub model of nservicebus. I have the following situation
My publisher is hosted a wcf web service and publishes the message.Thw wcf web config look like

```
<!--NSB configurations-->
<MsmqTransportConfig
  InputQueue="Pubque1"
  ErrorQueue="error"
  NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"+
  MaxRetries="5"
```

/>

And i am having one subscriber listening for the message in puque1 like

```
<MessageEndpointMappings>
    <!--Subscribe Test and Candidate creation messages-->
    <add Messages="Messages1" Endpoint="Pubque1@machine1"/>
    <add Messages="Messages2" Endpoint="Pubque1@machine1"/>
</MessageEndpointMappings>
```

Here the subscriber is not working.
Am i doing anything wrong.
Thanks,
Ajai

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What error are you getting? Does the example given with NSB work?  What does the rest of your config look like?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your NServiceBus initialization code, but my guess would be that you didn't configure a subscription storage for your publisher. It is very likely that when the subscription requests arrived at this endpoint that NServiceBus wrote an error to the log explaining this. The solution should be as simple as including .MsmqSubscriptionStorage() to your initialization code, or .DbSubscriptionStorage() if you want to scale out.